# Emotive Sculpture in a Port - Where Is It?

Tags: identify-this, landmarks

I was browsing through some photo archives and encountered this startling photo...

[image]

The photo metadata reveals that it was taken in 2005 with an Olympus camera, but nothing else of value.  Google images guesses that it is a 'sculpture' and nothing more.

The sculpture presents a wistful mother with child presumably awaiting the arrival of the father who is at sea.

The locale appears to be a visitor pier alongside a shipping port. The dress and hair style of the  figures suggest a temperate European location.  Possibly the Crimea?

It's an interesting sculpture and I would love to see the front of it and would happily arrange a detour to it if at all feasible.

Where is this port? Alternatively, who is the sculptor and I can research it from there.

Comment: See also http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3582/the-great-5-year-anniversary-bounty-bonanza

Comment: Seeing the answer, I’m amazed that you were able to place it as the Crimea just from this photo!  Did you really not have any other circumstantial evidence that helped you guess the region?

Comment: @PLL, clothing, hairstyle, woman's physique, led to an educated guess...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The statue is located in the port at [Odessa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odessa) and can be seen [here](http://ukraine3d.com/en/The_seaman%E2%80%99s_wife) and [here](http://odessa-guides.at.ua/load/odessa_sights/sailor_39_s_wife_monument/1-1-0-7).

> Created by the sculptor [Alexander Tokarev](http://art-brand.ru/artist/58/Alexander-Tokarev). It is the modest memorial,
>   dedicated to the faithful wives of seafarers and their children who
>   accompanied their husbands and fathers to [Sevastopol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Sevastopol_(1941%E2%80%9342)) in the autumn of
>   1941.

Comment: +1 here it is on tripadvisor: https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g295368-d5259015-Reviews-Sailor_s_Wife_Monument-Odessa_Odessa_Oblast.html